# Square Integrability vs. Absolute Integrability conditions in Fourier Expansion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a question regarding the conditions for a function to have a well defined Fourier expansion. In my textbook, Applied Partial Differential Equations by David Logan, Fourier expansions are first introduced for square integrable functions on finite intervals. I.e for:

$$f(x)\in L^{2}[a,b] \text{  or  } \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^2=M \in \mathbb{R}$$

This made sense to me and I didn't question it as this is the condition I have always seen presented in my physics courses.

However, further along in the text continuous Fourier expansions were introduced and the condition became absolute integrability over an infinite interval:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx=M\in \mathbb{R}$$

This came as a bit of a surprise to me as I have not seen this before. Scanning through wikipedia showed the absolute integrability condition, though also over an infinite interval. I have written off the fact that I have not seen this condition in my physics class to the assumptions being put on the functions we use there. However, the fact that square integrability was still introduced at first in my math textbook has thrown me off.

It seems that these two conditions are not the same (one says $f$ is Lebesgue integrable the other says $f^2$ is Lebesgue integrable) and that the interval matters, for instance consider $f(x)=1/x$.

On the interval $[1,\infty)$ $f(x)$ is square integrable but not absolutely integrable.

On the interval $[a,b]$ and $a\neq 0$  then $f(x)$ is both square and absolutely integrable.

If we consider $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}$ on the interval $[0,1]$ then $g(x)$ is not square integrable but is absolutely integral.

So I am a bit mixed up by these conditions. Is the condition actually square integrability when on a finite interval and absolute integrability on an infinite interval? Or was the author simply introducing square integrability with the Fourier expansion as a convenient way to introduce this idea into the chapter?

Comment: One needs a function to be in $L^1$ to define the Fourier transform in the usual way. A priori the Fourier transform is not defined on $L^2$. However, it is defined on the dense subset $L^1\cap L^2$ and can be extended to all of $L^2$ with Plancherel's theorem.

Comment: @copper.hat I see. I think my textbook call's Plancherel's theorem by Parseval's equality and presents a simpler formulation/discussion. Any recommendations on where I can go to find a more in depth discussion on this?

Comment: Rudin's Functional Analysis perhaps, although I find Rudin a bit terse.